# Truncation with tooltip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following erb tag. My text is truncated as I expected but the tooltip is not shown on the hover.

```
<%= truncate(user.name, :length => 20, title: user.name) %>
```

How the above code needs to be changed??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a HTML tag, its a ruby code which will not show title

you should try this

```
<p title=<%=user.name%> > <%=truncate(user.name, :length => 20)%> </p>
```

Comment: Should you put quotes around the value for `title`? Like this: `title="<%= user.name %>"`?